# Altering a jQuery load code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi can someone assist me with altering this coding I'm trying to remove the href page#.html loading and use a preloaded li with the text to populate the sclit div when a link is clicked.

```
<div id="sclit"></div>
<!-- old code
<a href="page1.html" class="para">Sci Lit 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" class="para">Sci Lit 2</a>
<a href="page3.html" class="para">Sci Lit 3</a>
-->

<ul style="display:none">
<li class="page1"> text text </li>
<li class="page2"> text text </li>
<li class="page3"> text text </li>
</ul>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".para").click(function() {
       // jQuery("#sclit").load(jQuery(this).attr('href')); // old code
        jQuery("#sclit").load(jQuery(this).attr('li'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to preload the href pages in each anchor into the `li` and then swap them out when the `a` is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just trying to eliminate the `.load` in which case you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GgMee/

Change the html markup to this:

```
<div id="sclit"></div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 1</a>
<div class="details">text for sci lit 1</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 2</a>
<div class="details">text for sci lit 2</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 3</a>
<div class="details">text for sci lit 3</div>
```

Where the `details` div after each link is hidden and contains the text you want to display when that link is clicked.

Then the jquery is this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".para").click(function(){
        $("#sclit").text($(this).next(".details").text()); 
    });
});
```

Clicking on a link, finds the `details` div after it and puts the text from it into the `sclit` div.

Comment: quick question, how would i preload Sci Lit 1?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you wanted correctly, the html i posted above is what you would want returned from the backend.  That way it will be there when they click and require no ajax.  If you want it to default to the text of sci lit 1 then you can either just populate it from the backend when you create the html or set it in your javascript on document ready.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(function() {
    // preload all li's with the content of each anchors href beforehand
    jQuery(".para").each(function(e) {
        var $li = $("<li />").load($(this).attr('href'));
        $("ul").append($li);
    });

    // now that data is already present in the li's (and if the indexes match up
    // which they should if your html is accurate) swap the divs html with 
    // the content of the corresponding li
    jQuery(".para").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#sclit").html($("ul li:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem correctly but if I am not wrong the requirement is

1. User clicks a li tag
2. the div sclit takes the text from the li tag.

If that is correct then this should do it

```
<div id="sclit"></div>
<!-- old code
<a href="page1.html" class="para">Sci Lit 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" class="para">Sci Lit 2</a>
<a href="page3.html" class="para">Sci Lit 3</a>
-->

<ul style="display:none">
<li class="page1"> text text </li>
<li class="page2"> text text </li>
<li class="page3"> text text </li>
</ul>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("li").click(function() {
       // jQuery("#sclit").load(jQuery(this).attr('href')); // old code
        jQuery("#sclit").html(jQuery(this).text());
    });
});
</script>
```